# CIFAR-10 CNN test accuracy is constantly low

Tags: python, keras

I'm in the process of developing a CNN for the CIFAR-10 Dataset using pure keras, but I'm constantly getting a test accuracy of about 60%. I've tried increasing the epochs and it actually increased the accuracy initially, but I've reached a point where increasing it doesn't change the accuracy anymore. What can I do to have a higher accuracy?

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import os


batch_size = 32
num_classes = 10
epochs = 200
num_predictions = 20
save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'models')
model_name = 'trained_model.h5'\


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255


model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=epochs,
              validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
              shuffle=True)


# Save model and weights
if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)
model_path = os.path.join(save_dir, model_name)
model.save(model_path)
print(model_path)

# Score trained model.
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print('Test loss:', scores[0])
print('Test accuracy:', scores[1])
```

Comment: I gave this a try but I notice that the validation accuracy reported for epoch 13 and onwards is at least 0.7. Although not as high as that reported by [some](https://benchmarks.ai/cifar-10), it doesn't seem too shabby.

Comment: Your code is an almost exact replica of https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py (may be helpful to state this when you write the question) but with some important comments removed. Those comments indicate the performance that you should be getting (75% after 25 epochs). If you are not getting this, it might be due to (a) dumb luck (b) a problem with your installation. If it is a problem with the install, you need to provide more details (e.g., install commands, o/s, etc).

Comment: @JamesBrusey I ran it again and I got the 75% accuracy. Seems like it was just dumb luck. How would I go about increasing the accuracy at this point? Would I need to change the architecture   (Ex: adding more comb layers) or add some noise to the training images?

Comment: I would start by going through the other examples for Keras - I think the more recent versions add augmentation, for example. Then, if you are feeling adventurous, take an example paper from https://benchmarks.ai/cifar-10 and try to reproduce. This can be hard work but it is really worthwhile to build your intuition.